# EF Core Mysql performance

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have Mysql database with ~1 500 000 entities. When I try to execute below statement using EF Core 1.1 and Mysql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.7-m61 it takes about 40minutes to finish:

```
var results = db.Posts
    .Include(u => u.User)
    .GroupBy(g => g.User)
    .Select(g => new { Nick = g.Key.Name, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count)
    .ToList();
```

On the other hand using local mysql-cli and below statement, takes around 16 seconds to complete.

```
SELECT user.Name, count(*) c 
FROM post 
JOIN user ON post.UserId = user.Id 
GROUP BY user.Name 
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Am i doing something wrong, or EF Core performance of MySql is so terrible?

Comment: is user.name indexed?

Comment: I dont think so

Comment: Try to enable logging of actual sql queries that are executed. I suspect that what is actually running is far from the query that you've written.
Take each one of those queries that EF generates and run them in mysql-cli and time them. You will find the bottleneck

Comment: Hmm getting lots of: The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([u.User], [u])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([u.User], [u])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
The LINQ expression 'orderby {[g] => Count()} desc' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are doing different things. Some issues in your LINQ-to-Entities query:

1. You call `Include(...)` which will eagerly load the `User` for every item in `db.Posts`.
2. You call `Count()` for each record in each group. This could be rewritten to count the records only once per group.
3. The biggest issue is that you're only using the `Name` property of the `User` object. You could select just this field and find the same result. Selecting, grouping, and returning 1.5 million strings should be a fast operation in EF.

**Original:**

```cs
var results = 
    db.Posts
      .Include(u => u.User)
      .GroupBy(g => g.User)
      .Select(g => new { Nick = g.Key.Name, Count = g.Count() })
      .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count)
      .ToList();
```

**Suggestion:**

```cs
var results = 
    db.Posts
      .Select(x => x.User.Name)
      .GroupBy(x => x)
      .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
      .ToList();
```

If EF core still has restrictions on the types of grouping statements it allows, you could call `ToList` after the first `Select(...)` statement.

Comment: Well your example has reduced query time to 144seconds, but also took 2GB memory. Still this is much worse than in mysql-cli. Anyway this is some progress.

Comment: I work with EF on a daily basis, and I've rarely run across queries that run more than a few fractions of a second faster in raw SQL than in EF (once fully specified and vetted). If your project team allows for it, I recommend that you swap EF Core for the full EF until the EF Core team announces that it is enterprise-production ready. The lack of database-side grouping (at this time) is what keeps my team's projects locked into EF 6, despite the shiny appeal of EF Core.